# boost::process system leaking file descriptors

Tags: c++, boost, file-descriptor, resource-leak, boost-process

It seems like boost::process::system is leaking fds:

Let's say I have this simple code to flush iptables config every 3 seconds (just an example):

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <thread>


int main(void)
{
  while(true)
  {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    boost::process::system(boost::process::search_path("iptables"), "-F");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If I observe the count of open file descriptors by listing `/proc/PID/fd |wc -l`, I can see that the count increases by one every 3 seconds. Eventually, when it reaches 1024, the program will abort, because the `system` call will throw an exception with `what()` stating that there are  *too many open files!*

How can I avoid this fd leakage? I'm using boost 1.69.

EDIT:
Replacing `boost::process::system` with `boost::process::child` does not seem to help, the `child` seems to also leak fds, no matter if it gets detached or not.

EDIT 2:
Valgrind log with `--track-fds=yes`:
https://termbin.com/d6ud

Comment: I execute the code on my machine (fedora25) and I can not see any leak of file descriptors as you mention, are you running the program with root permissions? what os are you using?

Comment: @camp0, interesting! I'm running it on Arch Linux, with kernel 5.2.4. I'm running the program with root privileges, yes. Does your boost version match mine?

Comment: Im running 1.66 and g++ 8.3.1, did you try to execute directly "/usr/bin/iptables"? should be easy to identify where is the problem on your code.

Comment: So I'm using 1.69 and 9.1.0, respectively. Using "/usr/bin/iptables" produces the same behaviour; it is still leaking fds. To clarify, the "iptables" command gets executed successfully (the firewall gets flushed). It just still leaks the fd for some reason.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is to valgrind the process and see what are that file descriptors to identify the issue.

Comment: Very good idea. I've run it in valgrind and linked a paste to the original post.

Comment: You could also visit `/proc/$(PID)/fd` and check with `ls -la` what fds are open.

Comment: @schorsch_76, it seems like it is a bug in the library itself. I will answer and close this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be a bug in the specific version (1.69) of boost, and not in the posted code itself. So upgrading boost/patching the bug solves this problem.

The bug report can be found from here: https://github.com/boostorg/process/issues/62